# How to pass variable values to another config parameters?

Tags: python, configparser, python-config

```
[plugin_jira]
maxuser=
finduser=
endpoint="https://nepallink.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/user/search?startAt=0&maxResults={maxi}&username={manche}%".format(maxi=maxresult,manche=user_find)
```

This is my config file , in the endpoints item why I am using the format is so that I can pass a variable to it in my script.The script where it is running is below ,my **main.py**

```
maxresult = config.get('plugin_jira', 'maxuser')
user_find = config.get('plugin_jira', 'finduser')
endpoint = config.get('plugin_jira', 'endpoint')
```

Now what I am confused is when I call the endpoints values in the script it just fetching what is in the config without the variable values that got defined just above it.

How can I make the variable value of `maxresult` and `user_find` added to endpoints which is defined to access it.

Comment: First of all, what are you using to read config file?

Comment: I am using ConfigParser

Comment: Don't use format in that file, just leave it with `{maxi}` and `{manche}`, use format after `config.get`: 1. `endpoint = config.get('plugin_jira', 'endpoint')`, 2. Check with if to be sure that endpoint is not None (null), 3. Use format function on `endpoint` variable in your code

Answer (score 0):

In your config file, import the variables from `main.py` as following.

Config file:

---

```
from main import maxresult, user_find
[plugin_jira]
endpoint="https://nepallink.atlassian.net/rest/api/latest/user/search?startAt=0&maxResults={maxi}&username={manche}%".format(maxi=maxresult,manche=user_find)
```

This will allow you to access the required variables to your endpoints.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This may solve but is really not a right way to do it,The config file wont look like a  config file,is it a standard